# MeteorJS and x-editable-reactive-template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, x-editable, meteor

I want to use x-editable-reactive-template in my MeteorJS project. My template looks like this:

```
  <template name="jobSeeker">
    <div class="items-form">
      {{> xEditable type="text" success=onSuccess placement="right" mode="inline emptytext="Your name..." value=usernameValue }}
    </div>
  </template>
```

My template helper looks like this:

```
    Template.jobSeeker.helpers({

      usernameValue: function()
      {

         Meteor.call('getProfileUsername',function(error, result) {

                if (error) return alert(error.reason);
                return result;    
                });   

      }
 });
```

Meteor method on server-side:

```
 Meteor.methods({ 

 getProfileUsername: function() {

   var user = Meteor.user();    
   var currentUsername = Meteor.users.findOne(user._id);
   return currentUsername.username;

}

});
```

User is saved in MongoDB and inside collection there is document with field username. But something isn't working! Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are returning value inside a method callback that will not return value to the helper

try this

```
Template.jobSeeker.helpers({

      usernameValue: function()
      {

         Meteor.call('getProfileUsername',function(error, result) {

                if (error) 
                    return alert(error.reason);
                Session.set("username",username);    
                });  
         return  Session.get("username"); 

      }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you man this is working, I will accept answer. Is my aproach any good. I am new in Meteor. Is using Session safe ?

Comment: I don't have much experience to tell you about security,but if you feel sessions are not safe look at this http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar they serve the same purpose as sessions. Read the doc and coming to the approach I do the same in my projects.